# Can asyntask in android auto stop their task?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an `Asynctask` that does some work in the background, and I define it like this.

```
MyAsynctask myAsynctask;
```

Then in my button click event I do something like this:

```
public void onClick(Event event){
    mAsynctask = new MyAsynctask(context);
    mAsynctask.execute();
}
```

When I run the code, the work that I do in the background always seems to work well. But I'm afraid to have two `AsyncTask` running at the same time if I press the button the second time when the first `AsyncTask` is not finished.

Is this likely to be an issue?

Comment: Do some printing inside doOnBackground. and you can lock your button until the asyncyask finish with onPostExecute

Comment: ah... nice and simple, thanks man

Answer (score 1):

You can check status of the task as follows:

```
int taskStatus = myAsynctask.getStatus();
```

The status can be any of the following:

AsyncTask.Status.PENDING

AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING

AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED

So you can do something like :

```
if(taskStatus == AsyncTaskStatus.RUNNING){
 //task is still running
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `yourButton.setEnabled(false);` in your `onClickListener` and the after the task is finished in `onPostExecute` of your `AsynchTasck` set your button enable again. something like this :

```
boolean myFlag = true;
public void onClick(Event event){
    //yourBusston.setEnabled(false);
    if (myFlag){
    myFlage = false;
    mAsynctask = new MyAsynctask(context);
    mAsynctask.execute();
    }
}
```

and then in your `AsynchTask` do something like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void void) {
      //after you ensure that your task was successful 
      // yourButton.yourButton.setEnabled(true);
       myFlag = true;           
}
```

You can also cancel your task when ever you want by this line of code :

```
task.cancel(true);
```

Comment: in my case, the button should be enable even when the asynctask is running :D

Comment: so just use a flag to ensure you run the asynchtask one time ;)